# 'Maps' visualisation missing in Kibana ES 7.10

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch

Looking at the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/maps-getting-started.html), it appears that the 'Maps' visualisation should exist in ES 7.10. However, I am unable to see it (all I have is 'Coordinate Map' & 'Heat Map').

[image]

I am running ES/Kibana through AWS Opensearch, could this be the cause?

Comment: Coordinate Map + Region Map = Maps

Answer (score 0):

Opensearch is a  fork of [Elastic's Elasticsearch and Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack/). [Maps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.10/maps-getting-started.html) is only available in Elastic's offerings.